# How To Add Style To WPF (C#) Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have followed a tutorial which told me to  create a copy of the DataGrid and then add some style on it. This file is currently named "DataGrid.xaml" however I do not see the changes on my actual DataGrid, it still looks like the classic DataGrid in WPF (C#)...How Do I go about it?

Comment: Either your application is incomplete, or tutorial is incomplete. In order to get help, you ought to share the not-working code with the community!

Comment: Can I add style directly into the code of  the gird?

Comment: Yes, you can, I'll demonstrate one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the style of the `Grid` inside the Grid's xaml code as follows

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```